# Polyfill js Date to use momentjs formatting

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to polyfill the js Date class with momentjs formatting. (Let's not go into discussions about why)

currently I have:

```
Object.defineProperty( Date.prototype, 'toDateFormat', {
    get: function(format) {
        return moment(this).format(format || 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    }
});
```

This should result in user typing `mydate.toDateFormat('MMM YYYY')` and get `'May 2018'`.

My only problem in `format` is `undefined` in the getter, I realised I cannot pass parameters to `Object.defineProperty` getter. In the app it works and resolves to default `'YYYY-MM-DD`, since `format` is `undefined`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Basically your not after using a getter,  so just attach to the prototype as normal..  `Date.prototype.toDateFormat = function(format) {...}`   Of course doing this to native built in's is still wrong.. :)

Comment: Thanks that solved it.

Comment: If you're going to do this regardless of advice not to modify built-in objets, why not just call it *format*? Then `Date.prototype.format = function(format) { ... };` and *someDate.format(...)*. Though if you're going to do that, you should probably also replace *Date.parse* with the momentjs (or some other decent) parser too.